# Is there any evidence ethylene (gas) has any detrimental impact on human health?

Tags: toxicology

Is there any evidence ethylene (gas) has any detrimental impact on human health? The only thing I was able to find is that the IARC doesn't consider it a carcinogen. But carcinogenesis is not the only way a substance can afflict human health, is it? The ATSDR only has ethylene glycol and ethylene oxide. But maybe it's oxidized after being emitted so the latter is relevant, isn't it?

[image]